# ¿Cómo puedo reordenar una data?

Tags: r

Estoy intentando reordenar las variables de una data frame pero no lo he logrado, ¿alguien sabe cómo se puede hacer?

```
factor <- c("A")
tiempo <- c(2006,2007,2008,2010)
var <- c(2,4,5,7)
df <-as.data.frame(cbind(factor,tiempo,var))
df
   factor tiempo var
 1      A   2006   2
 2      A   2007   4
 3      A   2008   5
 4      A   2010   7
```

Esta es la forma que quiero la data frame

```
 factor  tiempo1 tiempo2 var1  var2
      A    2006     2007    2     4
      A    2008     2010    5     7
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: mira la funcion, arrage, del paquete dplyr,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es combinar las filas pares con las impares, mi propuesta es técnicamente similar a la de Rafael Diaz, veamos:

```
new.df <- cbind(df[seq(1,nrow(df),2),],
                df[seq(2,nrow(df),2),])[, c(1,2,5,3,6)]

new.df
  factor tiempo tiempo.1 var var.1
1      A   2006     2007   2     4
3      A   2008     2010   5     7
```

Detalle:

- Con `df[seq(1,nrow(df),2),]` nos quedamos con las filas impares
- Con `df[seq(2,nrow(df),2),]` las pares
- Mediante `cbind()` combinamos las columnas de las dos partes del mismo `data.frame`
- Por último, seleccionamos las columnas y el orden final que va a tener nuestro resultado: `[, c(1,2,3,5,6)]`

Lo único que le faltaría para ser más preciso con tu ejemplo, es renombrar las columnas:

```
colnames(new.df) <- c("factor", "tiempo1", "tiempo2", "var1", "var2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que podría crear un código como el  siguiente:

```
tran <- function(df){
  d <- df
  n1 = seq(from = 1,to = dim(d)[1],by=2);n2 = n1+1
  d = cbind(d[n1,],d[n2,-1])[,c(n1[1],n2,n1[2],dim(d)[1]+1)]
  colnames(d) = c(colnames(d)[1],paste0("tiempo",1:2),paste0("var",1:2))
  return(d)}

tran(df)
```